# Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\|x\|} \chi_{B_1(0)}(x)$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Define $f: R^3 \rightarrow R, f(x) = \frac{1}{\|x\|} \chi_{B_1(0)}(x)$ (with $f(0) = 0$).

I would like to calculate the fourier transform $g(\xi) = \int_{R^3} f(x) e^{-ix\cdot \xi}dx$.

I tried using polar coordinates, but this leads to enormous expressions containing sin, cos etc.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Is $B_1(0)$ a ball of unit radius at the origin?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion we will use the notation for the spherical coordinate system $\vec{r}=(r,\theta ,\varphi )$. In this notation the function becomes

$$f(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{r}\chi _{B_1(0)}(r) $$

It is clear that this is identical to

$$f(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{r}\Theta(1-r) $$

where $\Theta $ is the Heaviside step function (we use capital letter to distinguish from the polar coordinate $\theta $). The Fourier transform is

$$g(\xi )=\int _{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{r}\Theta(1-r)e^{-i\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\xi}}d^3r$$

We can take $\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\xi}=r\xi \cos \theta $, where $\theta $ since this only fixes the coordinate axes in the inverse $\xi$-space. The volume element in spherical coordinates is $d^3r=r^2dr\sin \theta drd\theta d\varphi $ and thus

$$g(\xi )=\int _{0}^{\infty }\int _0^{\pi }\int _0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{r}\Theta(1-r)e^{-i\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\xi}}r^2dr\sin \theta drd\theta d\varphi $$

The intergrand does not depend on $\varphi $ and we can integrate and simplify to

$$g(\xi)=2\pi \int _0^1\int _0^{\pi }re^{-i\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\xi}}\sin \theta drd\theta$$

Using $\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\xi}=r\xi \cos \theta $ we have

$$g(\xi)=2\pi \int _0^1r\left(\int _0^{\pi }e^{-ir\xi \cos \theta}\sin \theta d\theta \right)dr$$

The integral in the brackets can be evaluated easily

$$
\begin{align}
\int _0^{\pi }e^{-ir\xi \cos \theta}\sin \theta d\theta&=-\int _0^{\pi }e^{-ir\xi \cos \theta} d(\cos \theta)=\int _{-1}^1e^{-ir\xi t}dt=\frac{e^{-ir\xi} -e^{ir\xi }}{ir\xi}\\
&=-\frac{2\sinh (ir\xi )}{ir\xi }=\frac{2\sin (r\xi )}{r\xi },
\end{align}
$$

where in the last line we used the identity $\sinh(ix)=-i\sin(x)$. Therefore,

$$g(\xi)=\frac{4\pi}{\xi} \int _0^1\sin (r\xi )dr$$

Integrating gives

$$g(\xi) =\frac{4\pi}{\xi ^2}(1-\cos \xi)$$

Comment: I have serious problems understanding your answer. Let's take line 8 to get a start: You seem to say that you would "change the notation" of the function $f$ by using polar coordinates, but for me this is not only a "change of notation" but rather compositing $f$ with the polar function. Thus you cannot only change the notation in the integral but have to use the substitution formula, in particular add the determinant rightly and simultaneously introduce polar coordinates for the exponential function as well, what does not happen.

Comment: Furthermore you seem to integrate over $d^3r$ (and $R^3$), but in polar coordinates we have $r \in R$. 

Before I can continue to understand your answer we have to fix this issues.

Comment: Well, what is the meaning of $x$ in your notation?

Comment: Notice that you are integrating over $\mathbb{R}^3$. This means that the differential should also be three-dimensional, i.e. $\mathrm{d}^3x$.

Comment: Unfortunately you did not understand my comments. [But to answer the second one: I do not distinguish in the notation of the differentials: $dx = d^3x$. However I was referring to the differential you used in your answer, line $8$.]

Comment: How can you write $d^3r$, when $r$ itself is one-dimensional? If you integrate over $R^3$, you would need two further components beside $r$ which I am missing.

Comment: $d^3r$ is just a notation for an infinitesimal volume element, for example in polar coordinates we have $d^3r=r^2\sin \theta drd\theta \varphi$, or in cartesian $d^3r=dxdydz$ and so on..

Comment: Do you have any other sources which show that 
$$g(\xi) =\frac{4\pi}{\xi ^2}(1-\cos \xi)$$
is the right result?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/214753/67712 with $R=1$ in our case.

Comment: I feel like I'm getting crazy reading the mathematics on this issue. Simply take the first term in your linked answer right away: The responder straightforwardly  writes $1/r$ while $r \in R^3$. Please tell me: How should I ever be able to understand this without being a physician "knowing" that it is possible to do this and that without thinking about any kind of mathematical foundation? 

(I do not intend to offend you and I certainly believe that this is (the physician...) way it goes, but I cannot achieve the smallest kind of satisfaction reading this)

Comment: I hear ya. Fourier transform of $1/r$ demands a higher level of mathematical rigor. However, in your problem $r$ is evaluated over $[0,1)$ and the troublesome behaviour of the integral at $\infty $ is of no consequence here. And it's a physicist, not a physician ;)

Comment: I finally believe that your result is correct. The reason that it is possible to introduce polar coordinates the way you did is that the scalar product and in particular $f$ itself are invariant under rotations. This implies $g(\xi) = g((0,0,\| \xi \|))$. So as your calculations may be correct unfortunately your arguments are not. You simply completely ignore the way the transformation formula (which implies the theorem about polar coordinates) has to be used and do not care if the integrals you write down are well defined.

Comment: The main point here is as mentioned the rotation invariance of $f$, otherwise we get (as I claimed it in my entry post) enormous expression of sin, cos, etc., which are impossible to handle properly.

Comment: Well it is obvious that the function is rotationaly invariant, since it depends only on $r$ and not on the spherical angles. To avoid the problem with sines we rotate the coordinate system to achieve $\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\xi}=r\xi \cos \theta $.

Comment: The integrals are well defined due to the unit ball!